# Arduino remote IRsend undefined reference error

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use Arduino to transmit a code. I keep getting an error upon compiling.

After tons of research, i couldn't find a solution. Can someone please see what i'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
#include "IRremote.h"

IRsend irsend;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
delay(10000);
//Power//
IRsend irsend;
unsigned long int iri = 0x80BF51AE;

irsend.sendNEC(iri, 32); //Power Code
Serial.println("Power");
delay(10000);

}
```

Here is the error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccV39V2V.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `loop':

C:\Users\user\Desktop\IRecord/IRecord.ino:15: undefined reference to `IRsend::sendNEC(unsigned long, int)'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Here is the IRremote.h:

https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/IRremote.h

Comment: Can you show IRremote.h, please.

Comment: And indent your code properly inside the { and } braces for clarity.

Comment: @PeterBennett I've added the Github link for it. Its exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have IRSend installed wrong.

[Did you follow the instructions from the homepage?](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/README.md)

> 1. Navigate to the Releases page.
> 2. Download the latest release.
> 3. Extract the zip file
> 4. Move the "IRremote" folder that has been extracted to your libraries directory.
> 5. Make sure to delete Arduino_Root/libraries/RobotIRremote. Where Arduino_Root refers to the install directory of Arduino. The library RobotIRremote has similar definitions to IRremote and causes errors.

Number 5 looks like a good candidate for the cause of your trouble.

Comment: I tried that and did not work unfortunately. I restarted the IDE aswell.